# How to use jQuery extend method to create a custom plugin for element or class selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to improve my jQuery/javascript skills and I think I have the perfect problem that may help me learn how and when to use the extend approach to an jQuery object. I am basically try to create a function that restricts the max-length of an `input[type=text]` element.

What I really want is this to be an example for users  on how to use jQuery extend $fn. to create custom plugins. While not an ideal usage, this example is simple as the user simply passes in some sort of value (min or max or both?) using the selector based off the class name and  then the plugin automatically updates the elements max-length/min-length and length value).

This is what I have so far but I know I am not on the right track yet. Or even better yet, also create another plugin that sets the `min-length`, max-length, `length` attributes. Please feel free to edit as needed. Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
maxLength(length,element) {

        if (element.val().length <= length) { 
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

}

$(".max-length").keypress(function (element) {
    maxLength(2,element);
});
</script>
```

What I want is that I can either

A: `$("Textbox).maxLength(2);` //Prefer this as this is how I would like to use it I think?

OR

B: `maxLength($("#Textbox"), 2);`

---

**EDIT**

Here is the closet examples I found but this is just an indicator/variable that extends the object not a method for a jQuery/js object:

$(document).tooltip.temporarilyOff
Then when I initialize the jQuery tooltip, I just need to add a check in the open:

```
var settings = {};
settings.tooltipClass = "tooltip";
settings.open = function (event, ui) {
    if ($(document).tooltip.temporarilyOff) {
        ui.tooltip.stop().remove();
    }
};

$(document).tooltip(settings);

//set the variable of the object 
$(document).tooltip.temporarilyOff = true;
```

Whats messed up is I guess I didnt know what I was looking for was a plugin. Doh! jQuery docs had my example the whole time. I guess now the passing of args is all thats left

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.
```

Comment: why not use the input maxlength?you can do this without js

Comment: check this this maybe what you want https://jsfiddle.net/jznxtgm0/

Comment: use keyup instead see this https://jsfiddle.net/jznxtgm0/1/

Comment: for A: $('input').attr('maxlength', 2) for B: see demo

Comment: It was more about me learning to increase functionality of jQuery objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

I extended the solution to pull the max length from a data attribute, so it can be more flexible for you.

```
<input type="text" class="max-length" data-maxlength="5"> <input type="text" data-maxlength="3" class="max-length" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

(function( $ ) { //Protect the $ Alias and Adding Scope
  $.fn.restrictLength = function(lengthVal) {
      //This plugin will work for all the elements that match the selector
      return this.each(function() {
        //Capture the keypress event and evaluate the input value length
        $(this).keypress(function(e) {
          //Make sure the data attribute is a number, else allow unrestricted max value
          //prevents hex and other number with alphas
          this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
          var dataMax = !isNaN($(this).data('maxlength')) ? $(this).data('maxlength') : ($(this).val().length+1);
          //Use the passed in value if it exists, if not use the data attribute (if it exists and is a nummber), else make it longer than the current value (not restricted)
         var length = !isNaN(lengthVal) ? lengthVal : dataMax;
         if ($(this).val().length >= length) { 
           //String is too long, don't execute the event
            return false;
          } else {
            //String length is good, allow the keyPress event to continue
            return true;
          }
        });
      });

  };
}( jQuery ));


$(document).ready(function() {
 // $(".max-length").restrictLength(4);  //Restrict all fields to 4 characters
  $(".max-length").restrictLength();  //Each field will be restricted to its data attribute value
})
</script>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/MyVRXd

Comment: please enlighten me why make a function that limits the user for input when you can use the maxlength attr of input?

Comment: Because the orignal poster said he wanted to learn about jquery through this exercise.  I agree that maxlength is a preferred solution to solve that exact problem, but as a learning exercise capturing key strokes, applying events to classes, reading data attributes, and preventing event actions are all covered by this problem. So why not?

Comment: No i am referring to the OP I am referring to you why would you make that one. Give a reason why make a function instead of using a maxlength.

Comment: Because that is what the poster asked for.  Using maxlength doesn't fulfill the poster's request to learn more jQuery.

Comment: Correct. If wanted to solve a problem specifically about maxLength I would just change the attr and for validation I would $.validator.addMethod('min-length', function (val, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || val.length >= $(element).data('min');
}, function(params, element) {
  return 'The field cannot be less than than ' + $(element).data('min') + ' length.'
}); and add new rule to validate() object

Comment: Its more about an example of jQuery.fn.extend. I guess I could look in an API to try and see how this is accomplished but I ffelt it would be better for a  an example to be worked out. Thanks for the example NOBrien! Thats a nice one on data-attr now if I can get one for B that would be awesome!

Comment: Yeah, i can do that for you tonight after I get off work.

Comment: @yardpenalty - I rewrote my answer to extend a jQuery function to restrict the length on an input field.  And updated my CodePen,  I included a link to the jQuery doc that outlines how to do it in more detail :).  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @NOBrien! I should have used the term how to create custom plugins because that is basically what I was aiming for. This is what I was looking for as a jumping off point. SO now I just have to build off this concept and create an entire custom plugin for a jQuery object. Thanks again for taking the time.

Comment: NOTE: The isNan() does allow hex and other numbers with alphanumeric so I added to your answer if that is ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109218/discussion-between-yardpenalty-and-nobrien).